# split doesnt work on a string using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i have a string as - 0-100
which is i am trying to split as 0 and 100

i have tried using jquery

```
$("#costFilter li a").click(function () {
                var temp = $(this).html().split("- ");
                var temp1 = temp.split("-");
                alert(temp1[0]);
                alert(temp1[1]);
                //                $("#<%=initialCost.ClientID%>").val(temp1[0]);
                //                $("#<%=endCost.ClientID%>").val(temp1[1]);
                //                $("#<%=BtnCostFilter.ClientID %>").click();
            });
```

which doesn't work.
My html as:

```
 <ul style="list-style-type: none" id="costFilter">
                        <li><a href="#.">- 0-100</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="#.">- 100-200</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="#.">- 200 - 300</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="#.">- 400-500</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="#.">- 600-600</a> </li>
                    </ul>
```

no alert is working. Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Again missing document ready handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you split the `html()` with  '- ' so your real value is in `temp[1]`
tyr this

```
$("#costFilter li a").click(function () {
            var temp = $(this).html().split("- ");
            var temp1 = temp[1].split("-"); //here
            alert(temp1[0]);
            alert(temp1[1]);
            //                $("#<%=initialCost.ClientID%>").val(temp1[0]);
            //                $("#<%=endCost.ClientID%>").val(temp1[1]);
            //                $("#<%=BtnCostFilter.ClientID %>").click();
        });
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/FdA8g/)

Answer (score 4):

First off, you should use `text()` instead of `html()` to get only the text of the anchor.

Second of all, as long as your strings are regularly formatted, you can use `substring()` instead of `split()` to get rid of the leading text. That will resolve the actual issue with your code which is the fact that the first `split()` returns an array rather than a single string.

The following code should do exactly what you're looking for:

```
var temp = $(this).text().substring(2).split("-");
alert(temp[0]);
alert(temp[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to clarify:

1. You are not using jQuery to split a string. That is just good old native javascript. jQuery is a library used to wrap a ton of functionality in interacting with the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model).
2. When you call `split()` this will return an array of strings split apart by the delimter. This means that attempting the following line will result in an interpreter error: `var temp1 = temp.split("-");` because `temp` is an array of strings, not a string itself.

api documentation for [$.map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)

That said, try something more like the following:

```
$("#costFilter li a").click(function () {
    var text = $(this).text();  
    var strings = text.split('-');

    // jQuery utility function that takes an array and creates a new one based on items
    // that are actually returned by the callback function (mine only keeps elements
    // that aren't empty)
    var filteredStrings = $.map(strings, function(str) { 
        if (str.length > 0) 
            return str; 
    });

    //do what you need with your strings now
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle that demonstrates how to this is used. http://jsfiddle.net/AVeeN/